# Get LCD To Work With pfSense

Tags: hardware, pfsense

I got a hold of a new firewall and got pfSense installed on it and setup, but after trying for a day I could not get the LCD to show anything after trying multiple drivers and settings. Hope someone has run into this unit before and had success getting it to work. The LCD lights up and only shows 2 ** on the top line to the very left.

Firewall: Talari

LCD: GFC1602AI

Driver: SPLC780D

Connection: RS232 - 3 cables

Other: EZIO-300

I was able to get LCDPROC started and get the client to connect but end result was always that no info showed up on the LCD.